# Searched text disappear after rotate screen

Tags: java, android, search, rotation

I have list fragment with default search widget, which searching in list. After search, list is reduced. Then clicked to item I show detail fragment. In detail fragment, I rotate screen and then click to back list fragment. This list fragment is not reduced, searched word is not in search widget. If I do not make rotate, searched word is in search widget.
How can stay word in search widget after rotate and back in search widget and list will be reduced?
Thanks.

Here is part of code.
Show detail:

```
@Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
      DetailBirdFragment frg = new DetailBirdFragment();          
      DetailBirdFragment.Bird = (BirdItem)l.getItemAtPosition(position);
      DetailBirdFragment.isPaused =false;
      DetailBirdFragment.isPlay = false;
      DetailBirdFragment.mTimer = null;
      FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
      FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
      transaction.replace(R.id.container, frg);
      transaction.addToBackStack(null);
      transaction.commit();       
  }
```

Search item by word:

```
@Override
  public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {       
      searchView.setQuery(ItemAdapter.FilterByOriginal, true);          
      ItmAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();               
      getListView().invalidateViews();

      return false;
  }
```

Create list fragment:

```
@Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);            

    ...         

    ItmAdapter = new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, birds);             
    setListAdapter(ItmAdapter);

    setRetainInstance(true);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
  }
```

**EDITED**

Ok, I put two PNG to illustrates a problem.
Before click on detail and rotate, I search:
[image]

after search, click on detail, rotate and click back:
[image]

I want to list will be same before rotate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found solution. onQueryTextChange was called twice. Firstly with searched word and secondly with empty searched word. I don't know why. So I make this modification and everything working.

In ListFragment:

```
  private static boolean wasPause;

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      wasPause = true;
  }

   public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {      

      if (wasPause && TextUtils.isEmpty(arg0)) {
          wasPause = false;
          searchView.setQuery(ItemAdapter.FilterByOriginal, false);
          return false;
      }
    ...
```